# Plotting glm interaction with 3 variables in R

Tags: r, plot, glm, interaction

I have the following logistic model with a categorical variable interaction which I wish to plot in R.

```
model<- glm(df5$combined == "No" ~ df5$rs_glm5scale * df5$scenario, family="binomial")
```

The scenario variable has two categories (A and B).

I aim to have a plot graph like this:
[image]

I've tried the following but it doesn't work for the y-axis:

```
glmplot<-ggplot(model, aes(x= df5$rs_glm5scale, y= df5$combined == "No", group=df5$scenario))+geom_line(size=1, aes(color= df5$scenario))
```

How would I plot this on a graph?

Comment: Please write a reproducible example so people can understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data grid to plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)    

model = glm(combined == "No" ~ rs_glm5scale * scenario, data = df5, family="binomial")

grid = df5 %>% data_grid(rs_glm5scale = seq_range(rs_glm5scale, 20), scenario)

grid$predictions = predict(model, newdata = grid, type = 'response')

grid %>% ggplot(aes(x = rs_glm5scale, y = predictions, color = scenario)) +
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Hello, thank your for your answer but I got these error messages when I run the code:   Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, predictions, value = c(0.445143406599034,  : 
  replacement has 170 rows, data has 40
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 40 rows but variables found have 170 rows

Comment: The second error message: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'predictions' not found

Comment: rewrite the definition of your model like this `model <- glm(combined == "No" ~ rs_glm5scale * scenario, data = df5, family="binomial")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using base R:

```
# First create a parameter grid to make predictions
grid <- expand.grid(
  rs_glm5scale = seq(min(df5$rs_glm5scale), max(df5$rs_glm5scale), length.out = 1000),
  scenario = c("A", "B")
)

# Then make predictions
pred <- predict(
  model,
  newdata = grid,
  type = "response"
)

cond <- grid$scenario == "A" # to select predictions corresponding to scenario A

# Plot the predictions for category "A"
plot(grid$rs_glm5scale[cond], pred[cond], col = "darkgrey",
     ylim = c(0, 1), type = "l", lwd = 2)

# Add a line for category "B"
lines(grid$rs_glm5scale[!cond], pred[!cond], col = "black", lwd = 2)

legend("bottomright", c("A", "B"), col = c("darkgrey", "lightgrey"), lwd = 2)
```

Comment: it doesn't give me the expected graph as I showed above

Comment: What are the differences comparing to the expected graph? Also, could you try providing a reproducible example? It would help us answering your question.